# How to transcript everything in console

Tags: powershell, office365

Hey i'm trying to get the device code that's being printed to the console in powershell when running "Connect-ExchangeOnline -Device". However it doesn't get appended to the output file along with everything else when I use start transcribe.

```
Start-Transcript -path "Path" -append
$DebugPreference = 'Continue'
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'
$InformationPreference = 'Continue'
Connect-ExchangeOnline -Device -Verbose
```

Expected output:

```
To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code CDWS27A56 to authenticate.
```

Actual output:

```
The module allows access to all existing remote PowerShell (V1) cmdlets in addition to the 9 new, faster, and more reliable cmdlets.

|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|    Old Cmdlets                    |    New/Reliable/Faster Cmdlets       |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|    Get-CASMailbox                 |    Get-EXOCASMailbox                 |
|    Get-Mailbox                    |    Get-EXOMailbox                    |
|    Get-MailboxFolderPermission    |    Get-EXOMailboxFolderPermission    |
|    Get-MailboxFolderStatistics    |    Get-EXOMailboxFolderStatistics    |
|    Get-MailboxPermission          |    Get-EXOMailboxPermission          |
|    Get-MailboxStatistics          |    Get-EXOMailboxStatistics          |
|    Get-MobileDeviceStatistics     |    Get-EXOMobileDeviceStatistics     |
|    Get-Recipient                  |    Get-EXORecipient                  |
|    Get-RecipientPermission        |    Get-EXORecipientPermission        |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|

To get additional information, run: Get-Help Connect-ExchangeOnline or check https://aka.ms/exops-docs

Send your product improvement suggestions and feedback to exocmdletpreview@service.microsoft.com. For issues related to the module, contact Microsoft support. Don't use the feedback alias for problems or support issues.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: take a look at >>> `Get-Help about_Redirection` <<<. i suspect that your non-captured info is using one of the other streams.

Comment: This led me to trying to redirect all streams using example 4 from the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.1

Unfortunately it didn't work, it logs the same information as you can get using start-transcript with the verbose switch

Comment: then the cmdlet is the problem. [*sigh ...*] the exchange module is ... notorious ... for behaving badly. i recommend you try various ways to capture the text to a $Var. then, if you find one that works, write that to your transcript.

Comment: Do you have any tips as to how one might go about that?

Comment: run the cmdlet and see if you can redirect the output to a $Var. for instance, try to redirect the error stream to the success/output stream & then catch that. don't go for ALL the streams ... try sending one at a time to the output stream & capturing that by assigning it to a $Var. ///// you may also want to post in the exchange or o365 subreddits for ideas.

Comment: Try `$test = Connect-ExchangeOnline -Device 6>&1` see if that works, don't use `-Verbose`.

Comment: Also, `-Device` is meant to be used on interactive sessions, I've seen your bounty question related to this. Can you explain why you can't use the unattended connection examples 3, 4 or 5 on [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/connect-exchangeonline?view=exchange-ps#example-3) ?

Comment: The unattended connection scenarios don't support delegation, for that you need to use the secure app model which is only supported by pssession, where not all commands work with delegation such as Get-MailboxFolderStatistics. I know it's not optimal but I'm trying to use the device switch as a workaround as I haven't found any other solution.

Comment: And I can't just use credentials since MFA is a requirement for delegation

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Using that still doesn't seem to give me any output